# Servicestack Deserialize Redis Response GetAllItemsFromList

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

So using lists within Servicestack/Redis, when pulling them back from the server I am getting a list of strings (which each the same CLASS just different data in each one).

I did not see a way of using "typed" lists which would allow Servicestack to serialize/deserialize as I add, get items from the List.  So my question is:

```
List<string> resp = rc.GetAllItemsFromList (key);
```

Gives me back a LIST (Collection) of strings.  Each one being a JSON representation of Class ABC.

I'd rather have a list of `<ABC>` returned.  If not, I know I can iterate through the collection of strings deserializing each.  But want to know if there is a better way to be doing this than that.

Answer (score 1):

To get a List of Types back you'd use the [IRedisTypedClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/Generic/IRedisTypedClient.cs) API and access the Typed List APIs in [IRedisList](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/Generic/IRedisList.Generic.cs) by accessing the `Lists[]` collection, e.g:

```
var redisAbc = redis.As<Abc>();
List<Abc> results = redisAbc.Lists[key].GetAll();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !! Thanks